# Fixing responsiveness issues inside our Canvas App

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have the following Canvas App:-

[image]

where i have a main Horizontal container which occupy the whole app , inside the Horizontal container we have 2 vertical containers (the green occupy 1/4 where the other occupy 3/4). inside the second vertical container we have a form and a vertical container which have 2 buttons.

now we are facing these 2 issues:-

1. the Save & Edit buttons are shown under each other while we want them to be beside each other.
2. on small sized screens the form input fields will be trimmed horizontally  (you can not view the end of each field), as follow:-

[image]

any advice how to fix those 2 issues?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change the position of buttons from the right side pane. Select the button, set the X and Y properties, or just drag it to the location you want.
2. This is because the aspect ratio of the smaller screen doesn't match with your app. If you want it to show better on ipad or phone, change the aspect ratio of the app from the settings to match that of the smaller screen.